# Twitter API search for hashtags - Some missing

Tags: php, twitter

When using the twitter search/tweets.json API, it doesn't seem to pickup all tweets matching the criteria (within the 7 day limit). A large number are missing compared to what I see direct on the twitter website.

Any tweaks or changes I can make, or am I stuck without paying them $1000's?

```
    $hashtagsearch = $exchange->setGetfield('?&include_entities=true&tweet_mode=extended&q=%23test&result_type=recent&since_id=1')
    ->buildOauth('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json', 'GET')
    ->performRequest();
```

Comment: Twitter has been restricting access to this sort of thing progressively for years now. You're stuck paying if you need an absolutely complete record.

Comment: They already mention in their doc that not all tweets are indexed and the search endpoint would return only "relevant"  tweets. You would have to opt for their paid service via gnip. But it is way too expensive.